# UIScrollView -> UIView ->UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am trying to create a horizontal UIScrollView with a few images in it. The user should be able to scroll horizontal between all the images. If he holds down the finger the scrolling should stop.

I though about making a

- UIScrollView (320 x 122 px)
- UIView for the content + really big width
- UIImageView for the individual images

Here is my code:

```
headScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 122)];
 [self.view addSubview:headScrollView];
 // Dafür einen contentView programmatisch festlegen
 headContentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, headScrollView.frame.size.height)];
 [headContentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
 [headScrollView addSubview:headContentView];
 [headScrollView setContentSize:headContentView.frame.size];

 headImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
 NSMutableArray *elements = [appDelegate getElements];
 for (int i = 0; i < [elements count]; i++) {
    headImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[elements objectAtIndex:i] nameOfElement]];
    [headContentView addSubview:headImageView];
 }
```

But it's not working. There is no image there :-( When I do a NSLOG i get 3 names of the images, so it should work...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using single instance of UIImageView. In a loop when you set the image, you are actually changing image of same UIImageView. Also you do not headContentView here.
1. Set the content size of the scrollview to fit 3 image views
2. Just add different instances of UIImageView by changing the frame while scrolling.

You can refer the sample 'PageControl'

Regards,
Deepa